# How to run request sequentially in a loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, request

This is a pseudo code of what I am trying to achieve. First I need to get a list of URLs from the request body then pass those URLs to request function (using request module) which will get the data from each url and then save those data to MongoDB. After all the requests are finished including saving data to the server only then it should send a response.

```
app.post('/', (req, resp) => {

    const { urls } = req.body;

    urls.forEach((url, i) => {

        request(url, function (err, resp, body) {

            if (err) {
                console.log('Error: ', err)
            } else {
                // function to save data to MongoDB server
               saveUrlData(body);
               console.log(`Data saved for URL number - ${i+1}`)
            }
        })
    });

    // Should be called after all data saved from for loop
    resp.send('All data saved')
})
```

I have tried this code and of course the resp.send() function will run without caring if the request has completed. Using this code I get a result on the console like this:

```
Data saved for URL number - 3
Data saved for URL number - 1
Data saved for URL number - 5
Data saved for URL number - 2
Data saved for URL number - 4
```

I could write them in nested form but the variable `urls`can have any number of urls and that's why it needs to be in the loop at least from my understanding. I want the requests to run sequentially i.e. it should resolve 1st url and then second and so on and when all urls are done only then it should respond. Please help!

Comment: `I want the requests to run sequentially i.e. it should resolve 1st url and then second and so on and when all urls are done only then it should respond` but no url is dependant upon the other one. So maybe you should make them parallel. Which will be way faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
app.post('/', async (req, resp) => {

    const {
        urls
    } = req.body;

    for (const url of urls) {
        try {
            const result = await doRequest(url)
            console.log(result)

        } catch (error) {
            // do error processing here 
            console.log('Error: ', err)
        }
    }
})

function doRequest(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
            err ? reject(err) ? resolve(body)
        })    
    })    
}
```

> using  [async await](https://node.green/#ES2017-features-async-functions-await)

Comment: `request` is not a promise based module you cannot directly await it. You need to promisify it first, or can use `axios`.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [JavaScript Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Otherwise, you can do a recursive request like so:

```
app.post('/', (req, resp) => {

    const { urls } = req.body;

    sendRequest(urls, 0);
})

function sendRequest(urlArr, i){

    request(urlArr[i], function (err, resp, body) {
      if (err) {
           console.log('Error: ', err)
      }
      else {
           saveUrlData(body);
           console.log(`Data saved for URL number - ${i+1}`)
      }

      i++;
      if(i == urlArr.length) resp.send('All data saved') //finish
      else sendRequest(urlArr, i); //send another request
   })
}
```

All I had to do is create a separate function I can call over and over again, passing the url array and a base index 0 as arguments. Each success callback increments the index variable which I pass in the same function again. Rinse and repeat until my index hits the length of the url array, I'll stop the recursive loop from there.

Answer (score 0):

You want to wait till all api response you get and stored in db, so you should do async-await and promisify all the response.
You can use Request-Promise module instead of request. So you will get promise on every requested api call instead of callback.
And use promise.all for pushing up all request(module) call inside array.
Using async-await you code execution will wait till all api call get response and stored in db.

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  try{
   const { urls } = req.body;
    // completed all will have all the api resonse. 
    const completedAll = await sendRequest(urls);
    // now we have all api response that needs to be saved
    // completedAll is array
    const saved = await saveAllData(completedAll);
    // Should be called after all data saved from for loop
    res.status(200).send('All data saved')
  }
  catch(err) {
   res.status(500).send({msg: Internal_server_error})
 }
})

function sendRequest(urlArr, i){
    const apiCalls = [];
    for(let i=0;i < urlArr.length; i++){
      apiCalls.push(rp(urlArr[i]));
    }
    // promise.all will give all api response in order as we pushed api call
    return Promise.all(apiCalls);
}
```

You can refer these links:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. But how do you catch errors with async and await? Like for example in the `sendRequest` if the `rp()` throws an error while resolving a url how would I catch that? And if any one the urls doesn't resolve would it stop resolving other urls?

Comment: To catch errors I have used catch block. When we use async and await that must be used in try catch block. If any of the method sendRequest or saveAllData throws error or reject the promise then it will be handle in catch block.
If any one url doesn't resolve then it stop resolving others and directly reject that  promise. Ideally there shouldn't be a error, we should have proper data validation before api call so we always get response 200.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the intention(a crawler) you can use `Promise.all` because the urls are not dependant upon each other.

```
app.post('/', (req, resp) => {

    const { urls } = req.body;

    const promises = urls.map((url, i) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, rej)=>{
            request(url, function (err, resp, body) {
                if (err) {
                    rej(err);
                } else {
                   resolve(body);
                }
            })
        })
        .then((body)=>{
            //this should definitely be a promise as you are saving data to mongo
            return saveUrlData(body);
        })
    });

    // Should be called after all data saved from for loop
    Promise.all(promises).then(()=>resp.send('All data saved'));
})
```

Note: Need to do error handling as well.

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways to solve this.

- you can use `async/await`
- Promises
- you can also use the [async library](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each)

  ```
  app.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
      const { urls } = req.body;

      async.each(urls, get_n_save, err => {
          if (err) return next(err);
          res.send('All data saved');
      });

      function get_n_save (url, callback) {
          request(url, (err, resp, body) => {
              if (err) {
                  return callback(err);
              }
              saveUrlData(body);
              callback();
          });
      }
  });
  ```